# Relation between $X\in L^p$ and $n^{-1/p}\sum X$ for i.i.d. sequence.

Tags: probability-theory, law-of-large-numbers

> Let $X_n$ be i.i.d. sequence of random variables and $p\in(0,2)$.
>   \begin{equation}
> \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n^{1/p}}\sum_{k=1}^n X_k \label{limit}\tag{1}
> \end{equation}
>   exists and finite with probability one, if and only if $E|X|^p<\infty$ **and** either $p\leq 1$ or $EX_k=0$.

**Small Step**
If (\ref{limit}) exists finite, and $p>1$, 
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{n^{1/p}}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n X_k
\end{equation}
since $n^{1-1/p}\to\infty$, $\frac{1}{n}\sum X_k\to 0=EX_k$.

**Question**
I am not sure what is the relation between (\ref{limit}) and $E|X|^p$.
 I tried to use the fact that $n^{-1}\sum |X_k|^p \to E|X|^p$ however couldn't bound it.
Statement suggests that if $p\leq 1$, $E|X|^p<\infty$ iff (\ref{limit}) exists immediately hence I expect it to be rather straightforward. I appreciate if one can advise a path for it.

Answer (score 0):

If (1) holds with a finite limit, then $\left(X_n/n^{1/p}\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ converges to $0$ almost surely. Using the version of the Borel-Cantelli lemma for independent events, we derive the convergence of $\sum_{n\geqslant 1}\Pr\left(\left\lvert X_n\right\rvert\gt n^{1/p}\right)$ from which finiteness of  $\mathbb E|X|^p$ follows.